# Creating Groups via Web Service

Tags: 2010, web-services, groups, spservices

I am trying to create groups on a SharePoint 2010 site via the `UserGroup.asmx` web service. I am using jQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Users%20and%20Groups&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices) to interact with the web service.

When I try to create a group (via the [AddGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774470.aspx) method) which is owned by a user it works fine:

```
groupName: "NewGroup",
ownerIdentifier: "UserOwner",
ownerType: "user"
```

When I specify another group as the owner I get a 400 error and a "Group cannot be found error":

```
groupName: "NewGroup",
ownerIdentifier: "GroupOwner",
ownerType: "group"
```

Using the same group name (GroupOwner) however, I can find it using the GetGroupInfo method of the `UserGroups.asmx` web service. I have also tried setting the `ownerIdentifier` to the ID of GroupOwner, which produced a 500 error.

Every example I can find of the AddGroup method only ever specifies users as `ownerIdentifier`.

I am at a loss at this point - does anyone have any suggestions as to either what I'm doing wrong or where I should be looking for more information?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an error in my code. I was not properly escaping the name of GroupOwner. I was sending `A&Z Group` and I should have been sending `A&amp;Z Group`.

Once I rectified that the new group was created with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [ULS Viewier](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) to aid you in debugging your problem.

But another options is to use [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185012.aspx) to work with the groups, like this:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var group = new SP.GroupCreationInformation();
group.set_title('Test');
group.set_description('Oh hai');
ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups().add(group);
ctx.executeQueryAsync();
```